# Mounting CIFS in Ubuntu 18.04 its read-only unlike in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, samba, root, cifs, read-only

This command executed as root, used to mount a writable samba folder in Ubuntu 16.04 :

```
mount -t cifs -o guest //server/folder /home/user/somefolder
```

Now in Ubuntu 18.04, the same command makes the folder read-only, and is only writable by root.

Someone suggested the execution of mount as a normal user, which exits with the error:

mount: only root can use "--options" option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the root ownership of the mounted share with your own by using the `uid=your-user-name` option. So your mount command would look like this if your Ubuntu user name is "souliaq":

```
mount -t cifs -o guest,uid=souliaq //server/folder /home/souliaq/somefolder
```